# Font size changing based on amount of text on page on mobile devices

Tags: html, css

I have a website with inconsistent font sizes on different pages. After a lot of experimenting, I found that the fonts (the links below the title that say "About, Poetry, etc") are correct as long as there is enough text on the website, but are wrong when the amount of text changes. Which is crazy. But here's the proof:

[image: This version is not working]

[image: This version is working]

In both the HTML and CSS, I always refer to fonts in terms of em not pt. And no tags are being deleted when I remove the text:

Doesn't work:

```html
        <div id="page_content" >
          <h1 class="section-titles"><strong>About</strong><br>
          </h1>
          <p id="reveal-on-small-display"></p>
          Lorem ip         
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<br/>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Page Content -->
```

Works:

```html
        <div id="page_content" >
          <h1 class="section-titles"><strong>About</strong><br>
          </h1>
          <p id="reveal-on-small-display"></p>
          Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum         
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<br/>
          <p>&nbsp;</p>
        </div>
        <!-- End of Page Content -->
```

I can attach the CSS and HTML in full if it's helpful, but essentially if I need to

Comment: This may be a red herring, but what is `<p id="reveal-on-small-display"></p>` doing?

Comment: I didn't even see that. When the resolution of the device is small enough, it changes <p> from invisible to visible, but that is literally doing nothing here, I don't think. I can remove it to see

Answer (score 0):

After many hours I've figured out it has to do with the cell phone resizing elements of the page.

Solved with:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
```